# Can't import Lean 4 packages

Tags: lean

I've made a Leanprover installation on Ubuntu 22.04 and used the stable toolchain. The `elan toolchain list` shows the following default

```
leanprover/lean4:stable (default)
```

I've made a test file called `test.lean` that contains the following

```
import Leanpkg
#eval Leanpkg.leanVersionString
```

When I run `lean test.lean` I get

```
test.lean:1:0: error: unknown package 'Leanpkg'
test.lean:2:6: error: unknown identifier 'Leanpkg.leanVersionString'
test.lean:2:0: error: unknown constant 'sorryAx'
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I don't know much about lean 4 but I do know that nobody is using stable. What happens if you switch to a recent nightly? I also know that a much better fit for this question would be the Lean Zulip chat, in the lean 4 stream. You'll get instant help there.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Does the same with nightly. Sorry, I'm new to Lean (just installed it), I didn't know about the Zulip Chat. I'll head to it right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
import Lean
#eval Lean.leanVersionString
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."